# Office.context.document.getFileAsync causing Internal Error when reading current document

Tags: office-js, exceljs

I am trying to read the current opened document (where the add-in will be ran) to upload it to a web service. But when I tried retrieving the file, an internal error occurs.
OS: Windows 10
Add-in Host: Excel
Platform: Scriptlab (will migrate to the visual studio when done)
Hope someone can help me.
Here's my code snippet:

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 10240 },
  function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      var myFile = result.value;

      myFile.closeAsync();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Error:", result);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: what's the error message? I would like to have a local repro, could you please share me  the gist via scriptlab? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab#save-and-share-snippets